# Set a Listener in a Service-based Class

Tags: android, android-service

Hy i have a problem to set the ServiceUpdateUIListener in the service to update the UI. It's wrong to make a new Service object and set there the listener and put it in an intent.

Code source is at http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=356 there i can't find how the set the listener and start the service right.

Calling:

```
TimerService service = new TimerService();
                TimerService.setUpdateListener(new ServiceUpdateUIListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void updateUI(String time) {
                        clock.setText(time);

                    }
                });

                Intent i  = new Intent(Timer.this,service.class); //service cannot be resolved to a type
                i.putExtra("ms", ms);
                startService(i);
```

Service:

```
 public class TimerService extends Service{

        CountDownTimer timer;
        Chronometer clock;
        public static ServiceUpdateUIListener UI_UPDATE_LISTENER;

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int ms = intent.getIntExtra("ms", 0);

            timer = new  CountDownTimer(ms,1000){
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60 ;
                    int minutes = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000*60)) % 60);
                    int hours   = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000*60*60)) % 24);

                    clock.setText( String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours,minutes,seconds));
                    Log.e("Timer", String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished));

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            }.start();
            super.onStart(intent, startId);
        }
        public static void setUpdateListener(ServiceUpdateUIListener l) {
             UI_UPDATE_LISTENER = l;

        }
```

Comment: Question is not much clear can you explain more...!

Answer (score 25):

The Service documentation has fairly complete sample code for implementing a service in your app that another part of your app can bind to and make calls on:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample

Just put your setUpdateListener() method on the Service, and call it once you get onServiceConnected() with the service.

So your code would be something like this:

```
public interface UpdateListener {
    public void onUpdate(long value);
}

class LocalService {
    // Like in the Service sample code, plus:

    public static String ACTION_START = "com.mypackage.START";

    private final ArrayList<UpdateListener> mListeners
            = new ArrayList<UpdateListener>();
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private long mTick = 0;

    private final Runnable mTickRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mTick++;
            sendUpdate(mTick);
            mHandler.postDelayed(mTickRunnable, 1000);
        }
    }

    public void registerListener(UpdateListener listener) {
        mListeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void unregisterListener(UpdateListener listener) {
        mListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    private void sendUpdate(long value) {
        for (int i=mListeners.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
            mListeners.get(i).onUpdate(value);
        }
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (ACTION_START.equals(intent.getAction()) {
            mTick = 0;
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTickRunnable);
            mHandler.post(mTickRunnable);
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTickRunnable);
    }
```

Now you can start the service to get it to start counting, and anyone can bind to it to register a listener to receive callbacks as it counts.

It is really hard though to answer your question very well because you aren't really saying what you actually want to accomplish.  There are a lot of ways to use services, either starting or binding or mixing the two together, depending on exactly what you want to accomplish.

Now you can implement your client code again based on the sample:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity implements UpdateListener {
    private LocalService mBoundService;

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            mBoundService = ((LocalService.LocalBinder)service).getService();
            mBoundService.registerListener(this);
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            mBoundService = null;
        }
    };

    void doBindService() {
        bindService(new Intent(Binding.this, 
                LocalService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mIsBound = true;
    }

    void doUnbindService() {
        if (mIsBound) {
            if (mBoundService != null) {
                mBoundService.unregisterListener(this);
            }
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mIsBound = false;
        }
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        doUnbindService();
    }
```

Comment: One thing to note about this code: Your listener callbacks are called from the thread in the Service that issues the callback, so if you're wondering fx. why a View in your Activity won't update on a callback then that's probably why.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what you want, but this is not the way to do it. It seems you're mixing up a lot of things.

The tutorial itself is a bad example to my opinion, keeping a static reference to an activity in a service seems to me bad practice; you would use binding to bind your service to an activity, or if you don't want to you can pass Intents around.

As far as I know instantiating a service like you do and setting a listener on it like that doesn't work. You get an error in the startService() call because the service instance isn't a class obviously; you should use `TimerService.class` instead. In your service you have an onStart(); [onStart() is a deprecated function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStart%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29), you should use onStartCommand() instead.

Now, if you have an activity in which you want to show a clock you don't need nor want the service to update its UI directly of course, but if you'd want the service to calculate a new clock tick for you, just call startService(); As long as your service is alive, sending a new start service intent will just call the onStartCommand() with the intent you're sending along.

If your clock is in an activity, setup a broadcast receiver inside your activity that and let your service broadcast an intent that can be received by the broadcast receiver you setup, with your new clock value passed along.

Answer (score -1):

MrJre is correct that onStart is depreciated and that you should be using onStartCommand().

If you want to get this to work, there is a better way.

I am doing something similar, as in wanting to update a UI from results happening in a service. This was not particularly easy. (In my opinion)

Here's how to do it: (First off scrap your existing code)

In UI class add:

```
public Intent service;
service = new Intent(thisContext, TimerService.class);
service.putExtra("ms", ms);
startService(service);

//bind service to the UI **Important**
bindService();

IntentFilter timerFilter = new IntentFilter("TimerIntent"); // Filter that gets stuff from the service
registerReceiver(myReceiver, timerFilter);

void bindService() {
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, TimerService.class);
    bindService(newIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mIsBound = true;
}

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
        s = ((TimerService.MyBinder) binder).getService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        s = null;
    }
};

public void releaseBind() {
    if (mIsBound) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mIsBound = false;
    }
}

// Now in this class we need to add in the listener that will update the UI (the receiver registered above) 
private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Get Bundles
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        /* DO ANY UI UPDATING YOU WANT HERE (set text boxes, etc.) TAKING INFO FROM THE "extras" Bundle ie: setting the clock*/
        //ie: int timerTest = extras.getInt("0");
        // Now update screen with value from timerTest
    }
};
```

Service File:

```
public class TimerService extends Service {

    public TimerService () {
        super();
    }

    private final IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();
    public Timer clockTimer = new Timer();  
    public int timer = 0;   

    // We return the binder class upon a call of bindService
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // After service starts this executes
        Bundle extras; 
        extras = intent.getExtras(); 
        /* Call a function to do stuff here. Like if you are a clock call a timer function updates every second */ 
        // Here's an example, modify to fit your needs. 
        clock();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        TimerService getService() {
            return TimerService.this;
        }
    }

    public void clock() {
        clockTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Some function ie: Time = Time + 1 // 
                    /* MAKE SURE YOU BROADCAST THE RECEIVER HERE. This is what you send back to the UI.  IE:*/
                    timer = timer+ 1; // increment counter
                    Intent intent = new 
                    //Bundle the timervalue with Intent
                    intent.putExtra("0", timer);
                    intent.setAction("TimerIntent");
                    sendBroadcast(intent); // finally broadcast to the UI
                } catch(Exception ie) {
                }
            }   
        },
        0, // Delay to start timer
        1000); // how often this loop iterates in ms (so look runs every second)
    }
```

There might be some syntax errors in this code as I've just modified my existing and working code to try and fit your needs. There will obviously need to also be some modifications depending on what you want to do. But follow this framework and you will be able to do what you are trying to do.

This works for me, so hopefully you can modify this to work for you. (Only thing I've left out are the imports, but you should be able to easily figure that out)

Key points:

- Bind service to UI
- Register listener in UI file to respond to the broadcast from inside the service.

Cheers.