# Android background BroadcastReceivers but dynamically create

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm currently trying to get broadcast receivers running in the background of my android application, which I've been told to use an event service for. At present my broadcast receivers work fine if you're in the activity within which they're registered

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW)) {
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "Battery's dying!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("LOW", "LOW");
            intent = null;
        }else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED)) {
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "Battery's discharging!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("discharge", "discharge");
            intent = null;
        }else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)) {
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "Battery's charging!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("charge", "charge");
            intent = null;
        }else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY)) {
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "Battery's okay!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("OKAY", "OKAY");
            intent = null;
        }
    }
};
```

in OnCreate:

```
    registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW));
    registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY));
    registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED));
    registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED));
```

Despite the issues that arise with leaking intentfilters by making them in oncreate, my current issue that that when I change activity these no longer run, I've read from the following: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html#startingservices_alarmmanager

That by placing these into an IntentService and starting this service, they'll run consistently, however this involves registering the receivers in the manifest, which gives me issues in that my application is planning on allowing the user to listen out for specific events IE: these cannot be created dynamically.

Is there a way to dynamically create broadcast receivers within a class, which runs in the background of the application and is triggered when the broadcast occurs?

Comment: Have you tried encapsulating them in a singleton class that would be set in each "activity"? Are you using any DI?

Comment: But then on closing of the application, the receivers would turn off?

Comment: Ah missed the persist when app is closed. Only way to accomplish that is with a service that runs in the background. (I'm currently working on something similar). A listener might work well for you needs  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659974/set-a-listener-in-a-service-based-class There's an example in one of the responses that seems like what you're trying to accomplish.