# Send data from service to activity without polling

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver, android-service-binding

I have a service which maintains connection (Bluetooth Serial Port or TCP connection) with an external system. When data is received on the connection, it should be pushed to the activity which can then parse and display it. Think of a dashboard with some gauges that responds to new data in real time.

I do not want the activity to poll the service for data. I want the service to "push" data to the activity when it arrives. How is this best achieved?

Should I make a broadcast from the service? The data (a stream of CSV lines) would be arriving continuously. I don't know if broadcasts are meant to be used this frequently - like several 10s of updates per second.

What is the standard way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be two approaches:

**1. Use LocalBroadcastReceiver**

Register a Receiver in you Activity which will listen to the changes and update the UI accordingly.

**2. Bind the service and pass the Listener Interface.**

Create and implement a Listener Interface, then after Binding the service, pass this implementation of Interface to the Service. Whenever data is updated call the implementation method. You can follow this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659974/set-a-listener-in-a-service-based-class) to do so. This would be ideal for frequent updates